# MYSQL: Verificar que folio existente no aparezca en otra tabla, de no aparecer aumentar su valor en +1

Tags: mysql

Hola que tal amigos necesito de su ayuda, tengo dos tablas, una tabla llamada usuarios donde llevo el registro de personas con sus datos personales y cantidades a cobrar, incluyendo los pagos vencidos y otra tabla llamada por el mes en que se realizara el registro de los pagos ejemplo tablaJunio2022 donde llevo el registro de las personas que han llegado a pagar, mi idea es realizar una consulta en MySQL en la que verifique de acuerdo a los folios registrados en la tabla usuarios que folio no llego a pagar en el mes e incrementar en +1 lo que hay en la tabla usuarios del campo vencidos, es decir si lleva 5 vencidos aumentar en +1=6 para llevar el control de meses que no ha llegado a realizar sus pagos, de antemano les agradezco sus valiosas respuestas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el ejemplo que colocaste, Daniela no ha pagado desde que inicio el 2022, mientras que Oscar no ha pagado desde abril. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: es correcto amigo! le eh dado vueltas pero no encuentro como hacerle.

Comment: ¿Y el folio que estas almacenando en tablaUsuario es el ultimo folio que se registra en una tabla mes?

Comment: el folio que existe en tabla usuario son los folios existentes y los que abra a futuro por ejemplo que actualmente tuviera 20 registros del 1 al 20 de folios pero puede que mañana registre otros 10 y después otros 2, por eso la tablausuario es el punto de partida de los folios que existen y de donde se evaluara en las tablas de cada mes quienes no llegaron a pagar.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, necesitas almacenar en algún lugar cuando fue que inicio el pago. Sino, nunca sabrás exactamente desde que mes empezar a contar los vencidos.

Segundo, para como manejas las tablas, lo que harás será que crearas una tabla por mes, ¿no? No te lo recomiendo en lo absoluto. A la larga esto te consumirá mucha memoria en el servidor, sin mencionar que cada mes que pase, tendrás que actualizar las consultas. Lo mejor seria que crearas una única tabla y allí almacenes cada pago que hace el cliente, así como también la fecha en la que lo hace. Puedes almacenar fecha y hora con `DATETIME`, o solo la fecha con `DATE`.

Ahora bien, lo único que requieres es saber si un folio existe en una tabla o no, y en consiguiente aumentar el valor de un campo, ¿no?

Puedes hacer esto:

```
UPDATE tablaUsuarios             /* <— Actualizamos tablaUsuarios*/
SET vencidos = vencidos + 1      /* <— Sumamos +1 en el campo*/
WHERE folio NOT IN (             /* <— Especificamos que solo queremos */
                                 /*    actualizar aquellos registros que*/
                                 /*    que no encontremos su folio en la*/
                                 /*    siguiente consulta */
SELECT folio FROM tablaJunio2022 /* <— Hacemos un consulta que nos devolverá*/
                                 /*    aquellos folios que existen la tabla */
                                 /*    que deseemos consultar */
);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo que pasa que había echo el sistema de esa manera generar sus pagos pero cuando hablamos de un sistema de pago de servicios estos, son continuos mas si es para un municipio, entonces si genero las fechas tengo que generar por ejemplo fechas de cada uno de los usuarios por unos 7 años para olvidarme un rato del sistema, el problema recae que se vuelve lento, no eh encontrado una forma factible de manejar las fechas y no se vuelva lento en las consultas u acciones, alguna otra idea amigo?